Flutter river pod ref.read not calling the callbacks
I have as simple river pod provider (for testing) but it is not calling the compeltion callbacks.
I am using below package to scan barcode with camera and once barcode is retrived I am calling the provider funtion.
pub: ai_barcode_scanner: ^5.1.1


MobileScanner(
  onDetect: (p0) {
    if (p0 == null) {
      return;
    }

    if (p0.barcodes == null || p0.barcodes.isEmpty) {
      return;
    }

    final barcode = p0.barcodes.first.rawValue.toString();

    ref.read(boredSuggestionProvider).when(data: (d) {
                print(d);
              }, error: (e, s) {
                print(e);
              }, loading: () {
                print("loading");
              }); // this is a test provider but same issue with this as well.
  },
...



@Riverpod(keepAlive: true)
Future<String> boredSuggestion(BoredSuggestionRef ref) async {
    final json = {
            'activity': 'Go to the gym and do some exercise.',
            'qwe': 'asdsd'
            };
    return json['activity']! as String;
}

Only loading gets printed and data print function doesn't get executed.
